# Longest Palindrome

Tags: english, palindrome

What is the longest palindrome created?

**For those who don't know**
A palindrome is a word or series of words that read the same forwards as backwards. For example:

hannah

A man a plan a canal Panama

**Some Rules**

- The Palindrome must be in English.
- The Palindrome must make sense. By this I mean it cannot be simply a series of words that do not make a coherent sentence/string of sentences.
- Punctuation/capitals can be ignored.
- Odd phrasing/grammar is allowed as long as it still makes sense.

Comment: Check out  http://norvig.com/palindrome.html

Comment: @Garnow, these palindromes are long but don't make sense.

Comment: "Makes sense" can be subjective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has very little to do with puzzles, either creating them or solving them.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I can't see the difference between this and questions like longest alphabetical sentence.

Comment: @Sam You're not asking people to come up with original solutions; you're just asking a trivia question.

Comment: The problem with this question is that there's no upper bound. Any palindrome that such that one sentence can be read the same way backwards as forwards can be tacked onto the beginning / end of another. For example, if we have palindrome of the form X,reverse(X) s.t. X and reverse(X) are both separate sentences, and we have a similar construction Y, reverse(Y), we can simply construct the palindrome X,Y,reverse(Y),reverse(X).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Palindromic Poem

> Mood's mode!
> Pallas, I won!
> (Diaper pane, sold entire.)
> Melt till ever sere, hide it.
> Drown a more vile note;
> (Tar of rennet.)
> Ah, trowel, baton, eras ago.
> The reward? A "nisi." Two nag.
> Otary tastes putrid, yam was green.
> Odes up and on; stare we.
> Rats nod. Nap used one-erg saw.
> (May dirt upset satyr?)
> A toga now; 'tis in a drawer, eh?
> Togas are notable.
> (Worth a tenner for Ate.)
> Tone liver. O Man, word-tied I.
> Here's revel!
> Little merit, Ned? Lose, Nap?
> Repaid now is all apedom's doom.

If you are looking for a single sentence then...

> Lid of fade, metallic soot, emit Garret-simple, help mister ragtime to oscillate me, daffodil.

It have 75 letters.

Now if nonsensical palindromes in one sentence are allowed then

> A man, a plan, a caret, a ban, a myriad, a sum, a lac, a liar, a hoop, a pint, a catalpa, a gas, an oil, a bird, a yell, a vat, a caw, a pax, a wag, a tax, a nay, a ram, a cap, a yam, a gay, a tsar, a wall, a car, a luger, a ward, a bin, a woman, a vassal, a wolf, a tuna, a nit, a pall, a fret, a watt, a bay, a daub, a tan, a cab, a datum, a gall, a hat, a fag, a zap, a say, a jaw, a lay, a wet, a gallop, a tug, a trot, a trap, a tram, a torr, a caper, a top, a tonk, a toll, a ball, a fair, a sax, a minim, a tenor, a bass, a passer, a capital, a rut, an amen, a ted, a cabal, a tang, a sun, an ass, a maw, a sag, a jam, a dam, a sub, a salt, an axon, a sail, an ad, a wadi, a radian, a room, a rood, a rip, a tad, a pariah, a revel, a reel, a reed, a pool, a plug, a pin, a peek, a parabola, a dog, a pat, a cud, a nu, a fan, a pal, a rum, a nod, an eta, a lag, an eel, a batik, a mug, a mot, a nap, a maxim, a mood, a leek, a grub, a gob, a gel, a drab, a citadel, a total, a cedar, a tap, a gag, a rat, a manor, a bar, a gal, a cola, a pap, a yaw, a tab, a raj, a gab, a nag, a pagan, a bag, a jar, a bat, a way, a papa, a local, a gar, a baron, a mat, a rag, a gap, a tar, a decal, a tot, a led, a tic, a bard, a leg, a bog, a burg, a keel, a doom, a mix, a map, an atom, a gum, a kit, a baleen, a gala, a ten, a don, a mural, a pan, a faun, a ducat, a pagoda, a lob, a rap, a keep, a nip, a gulp, a loop, a deer, a leer, a lever, a hair, a pad, a tapir, a door, a moor, an aid, a raid, a wad, an alias, an ox, an atlas, a bus, a madam, a jag, a saw, a mass, an anus, a gnat, a lab, a cadet, an em, a natural, a tip, a caress, a pass, a baronet, a minimax, a sari, a fall, a ballot, a knot, a pot, a rep, a carrot, a mart, a part, a tort, a gut, a poll, a gateway, a law, a jay, a sap, a zag, a fat, a hall, a gamut, a dab, a can, a tabu, a day, a batt, a waterfall, a patina, a nut, a flow, a lass, a van, a mow, a nib, a draw, a regular, a call, a war, a stay, a gam, a yap, a cam, a ray, an ax, a tag, a wax, a paw, a cat, a valley, a drib, a lion, a saga, a plat, a catnip, a pooh, a rail, a calamus, a dairyman, a bater, a canal - Panama!

Comment: That's a lot of things involved in the construction of a canal.

Comment: What is a wet?!

Comment: @CodeNewbie a wet (UK)- "A person who is physically weak and ineffectual"